# Extracting Text from HTML Using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

My code is as below:

```
s = """<P><A>This is the topic</A>
This is the text</P>
<P>&nbsp;</P>
<P><A>Another Topic</A>:
Another Text </P>"""
for s in soup.findAll('a'):
   print s.text
```

Output is:

```
This is the topic
Another Topic
```

I want to get "This is the text" and also "Another Text". But somehow I cannot using this code. The condition is that I have to use a for loop. So if anyone knows how to extract the required text, it would be of great help.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried using - for s in soup.findAll('a'):
   print s.parent.text     ...It worked

Comment: With s.parent.text I obtain all the text concatened for all the paragraphs , something like this : _This is the topicThis is the text_

Answer (score 1):

Try to obtain the text inside the paragraph tag :

```
s = '<P><A>This is the topic</A>This is the text</P><P>&nbsp;</P><P><A>Another Topic</A>:Another Text </P>'
```

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

```
for s in soup.findAll('p'):
    #if the contents[1] have the NavigableString
    if len(s.contents) > 1:
      print s.contents[1] + '\n'
```

The output is :

```
This is the text

:Another Text
```